# how to not print a function when the function is not called

Tags: python

I have a messageBox that display information when an appointment is booked.

I added a function that calculate the distance between 2 points and displays it in the messagebox. But this function is only called if a specific condition is met.

If the condition is met, in the msgbox, it will display something like `booking 10 july, 9am-10am, distance in minutes: 30 minutes.`

but when the the function is not called, there should be nothing to display for `Distance in minutes`.

Instead, i receive this error :  `local variable "Distance" referenced before assignment`

I would just like to have it empty if the function has not been called.

this is the part of the msgbox code :

`"Distance in minutes: " + str(distance / 60)`

Comment: [Catch the error](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions) and construct a string to your liking in the except suite. Without more context it will be hard to give a better answer. Please read [mre].

Comment: If the condition is met, calculate the distance and set a variable to the distance output string.  Otherwise set the same variable to the empty string.  Then add the value of the variable to the messageBox text.

Comment: thank you so much! It worked.. I did : `Try` and pasted the first print and `except Exception as e` and pasted the second print. Worked perfectly!

Comment: @DennisSparrow mind giving me an example? seems less taxing that adding a try catch. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I'm posting this as an answer because code blocks don't seem to work well in comments.

Initialize a distance output string to the empty string.  If the condition is met, calculate the distance and put appropriate text in the distance output string. Otherwise, the distance output string remains empty.  Then concatenate the distance ouput string to the preceding, always-there messageBox text.

You didn't post much code, so the example must rely heavily on imaginary functions and variables:

```
distance_msg = ""
if doing_distance:
    distance = distance_in_seconds()
    distance_msg = ", Distance in minutes: " + str(distance / 60)

booking_msg = format_booking_message()
messagebox_text = booking_msg + distance_msg
```

Catching the exception from a reference to an unassigned variable, as suggested by @wwii, can also work.